# Is O.K to use the correlation between the values predicted by NLS and the actual values for the goodness of fit?

Tags: r, regression, correlation, nonlinear-regression

Reading about goodness of fits, I found that non-linear regressions fits are not measured by $R^2$. Recommended me to use the correlation between the predicted values and the experimental values.

It's correct to do that? (I'm using R)

```
Resd <- c(52.67, 46.80, 41.74, 40.45)
qep <- c(1.73, 1.84, 1.79, 1.45)

df <- data.frame(Resd,qep)

model <- nls(formula = qep ~ (Q0*b*Resd)/(1+(b*Resd)),
    data = df,
    start = list(Q0=2.86, b=0.032))

cor(df$qep,predict(model))

[1] 0.4837395
```

Answer (score 1):

Correlation is definitely not a good measure of regression accuracy. Suppose for the sake of argument (just a toy example), that your predicted values $\hat{y}_i$ are exact multiples of the experimental values $y_i$, i.e. $y_i = a\cdot \hat{y}_i$, with $a>0$. Then your correlation coefficient is going to be 1, but the errors between your predicted and experimental values could be huge if $a$ is very small ($a=0.01$) or very large ($a=100$). It's possible that the NLS function in R takes care of such scaling issues, but this example was just to illustrate why correlation could be misleading.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with Dshirodkar.
If you revise any econometric book, the general formulation of R2 is the squared correlation between the actual $y$ and predicted values $\hat{y}$:

$R^2=\frac{[\sum{(y-E(y))(\hat{y}-E(\hat{y}))}]^2}{\sum(y-E(y))^2\sum(\hat{y}-E(\hat{y}))^2}$

and in fact, this is the same formula that is recommended when nonlinear/semiparametric regressions are considered.

His argument of being careful about the scale $a$ is not valid because NLS starts with the assumption that $E(y)=E(\hat{y})$

That being said. If you are concern that your estimator is biased, which implies $a\not=1$, you can also use the mean squared error. This, however, would have to be compared to other competing models.

$MSE=n^{-1}\sum{(y-\hat{y})^2} $